# core3.0 docker container crashing with no status

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core 3.0 preview application that runs fine on my Windows box.  I move it to linux (Ubuntu 18.04), running on docker there.  It builds and runs fine.  I'm using NETGeographic library, which relies on Geographic.dll.  When it gets to the point of executing a function that relies on NETGeographic, it crashes silently.  No exception thrown, no anything.  Just a full on crash.

I've tried release / debug, publishing as a self-contained application, messing with hint and other paths, and I just can't get it to go for whatever reason on Linux.  For some reason I thought it was working before, and I see new files published as of today.  Is this a possible regression?  Is there an open bug on referencing this anywhere?  I haven't been able to find one.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Test.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "Test.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "Test.csproj" -c Debug -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Test.csproj" -c Debug --self-contained --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64 -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR "/src/"
COPY Geographic.dll /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.dll"]
```

output when ran:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: /app
Before LLAtoXYZ
user@server:~$
```

function call is just Convert XYZtoLLA from NetGeographic.  I've put the code in / out of a try/catch block with no change.  I've put logging in the catch, it never hits it, and so on.  Just crash to console.  Other api endpoints that do other things work great and never crash, including ones that use of dll's.  But whenever I use NETGeographic, it does, I assume because it's a wrapper around the C++ Geographic.dll lib?  Shouldn't this work?

Comment: What is your current csproj content? Do you target project to .netstandard or framework? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Let me work on a demo project to reproduce.  I'm having to scramble to fix.    
We have a .Net Core 3.0 Web API application which in turn references a .Net Standard 2.0 application for talking to the hardware devices (this is a static instantiation.  This application references a couple of libraries, some NuGet, some not.  One of these that is not nuget is NETGeographic.dll, which is a wrapper over Geographic.dll, so all the build steps carry Geographic.dll around with them.    
If there was referencing issue, I'd expect an exception.  Not a complete crash.